# JavaScript: Add score to saved score

Tags: javascript, html

So you'll find an if-statement marked in the snippet to inspect. If you run the snippet you'll notice the score adds when the character meets the coin. When the character is not at the coin, the score then returns to 0.

How can we save the score until 'isTouching()' is true again? Adding to it again and again, each time the coin is met. To confirm, the coin is supposed to move.

Thank you!

```js
function isTouching(a, b) {
    const aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    const bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

    return !(
        aRect.top + aRect.height < bRect.top ||
        aRect.top > bRect.top + bRect.height ||
        aRect.left + aRect.width < bRect.left ||
        aRect.left > bRect.left + bRect.width
    );
    
}

const avatar = document.querySelector('#player');
const coin = document.querySelector('#coin');


window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.key==='ArrowDown' || event.key==='Down'){
        const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
        avatar.style.top = `${currTop + 50}px`;
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up'){
        const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
        avatar.style.top = `${currTop - 50}px`;
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'Right'){
        const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
        avatar.style.left = `${currLeft + 50}px`;
        avatar.style.transform = 'scale(1,1)';
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'Left'){
        const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
        avatar.style.left = `${currLeft - 50}px`;
        avatar.style.transform = 'scale(-1,1)';
    };
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const scoreLabel = document.querySelector('#score');
    let scoreCount = 0;
    if (isTouching(avatar, coin)) {
        scoreCount++;
    };
    scoreLabel.textContent = scoreCount;

    if(isTouching(avatar, coin)) moveCoin();
    });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



const extractPos = (position) => {
    if (!position) return 50;
    return parseInt(position.slice(0,-2))
};



const moveCoin = () => {
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerWidth)
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerHeight)
    coin.style.top = `${y}px`;
    coin.style.left = `${x}px`;
};
moveCoin();
```

```css
#player {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

#coin {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
}

#scoreBoard {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    border: 8px solid #FFD700;
}

label {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Coin Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="player" src="https://media.tenor.com/images/0791eb3858075aca85eed5ecfe08c778/tenor.gif" alt="">
  <img id="coin" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/coin-gif-png-7.gif" alt="">

<div id="scoreBoard">
  <label id="score">0</label>
</div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score is getting initialized to 0 every time the listener runs, instead, you can use a global variable or you could save the score as `textContent` of the div with `id` "score".

Another small improvement would be to do the moveCoin and increment score in the same `if (isTouching)` block instead of two if blocks

```js
function isTouching(a, b) {
const aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
const bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

return !(
    aRect.top + aRect.height < bRect.top ||
    aRect.top > bRect.top + bRect.height ||
    aRect.left + aRect.width < bRect.left ||
    aRect.left > bRect.left + bRect.width
);
}

const avatar = document.querySelector('#player');
const coin = document.querySelector('#coin');

window.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
if (event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'Down') {
    const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
    avatar.style.top = `${currTop + 50}px`;
} else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up') {
    const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
    avatar.style.top = `${currTop - 50}px`;
} else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'Right') {
    const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
    avatar.style.left = `${currLeft + 50}px`;
    avatar.style.transform = 'scale(1,1)';
} else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'Left') {
    const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
    avatar.style.left = `${currLeft - 50}px`;
    avatar.style.transform = 'scale(-1,1)';
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isTouching(avatar, coin)) {
    incrementScore();
    moveCoin();
}
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const incrementScore = () => {
  const score = Number(document.getElementById('score').textContent);
  document.getElementById('score').textContent = score + 1;
};

const extractPos = (position) => {
  if (!position) return 50;
  return parseInt(position.slice(0, -2));
};

const moveCoin = () => {
  const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
  coin.style.top = `${y}px`;
  coin.style.left = `${x}px`;
};

moveCoin();
```

```css
#player {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

#coin {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
}

#scoreBoard {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    border: 8px solid #FFD700;
}

label {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Coin Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="player" src="https://media.tenor.com/images/0791eb3858075aca85eed5ecfe08c778/tenor.gif" alt="">
  <img id="coin" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/coin-gif-png-7.gif" alt="">

<div id="scoreBoard">
  <label id="score">0</label>
</div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Abito, wow. I have been trying to do it this way also, with a function and a +1. You clearly undertand scope and your experience with functions has been a boost to me. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `let scoreCount = 0;` is defined inside the event listener and once the event finishes and the variable is destructed with the value.

Simplest solution is to move `let scoreCount = 0;` to after `const coin = document.querySelector('#coin');` directly as below

```js
function isTouching(a, b) {
    const aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    const bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();

    return !(
        aRect.top + aRect.height < bRect.top ||
        aRect.top > bRect.top + bRect.height ||
        aRect.left + aRect.width < bRect.left ||
        aRect.left > bRect.left + bRect.width
    );
    
}

const avatar = document.querySelector('#player');
const coin = document.querySelector('#coin');
    let scoreCount = 0;


window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.key==='ArrowDown' || event.key==='Down'){
        const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
        avatar.style.top = `${currTop + 50}px`;
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up'){
        const currTop = extractPos(avatar.style.top);
        avatar.style.top = `${currTop - 50}px`;
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight' || event.key === 'Right'){
        const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
        avatar.style.left = `${currLeft + 50}px`;
        avatar.style.transform = 'scale(1,1)';
    }
    else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft' || event.key === 'Left'){
        const currLeft = extractPos(avatar.style.left);
        avatar.style.left = `${currLeft - 50}px`;
        avatar.style.transform = 'scale(-1,1)';
    };
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const scoreLabel = document.querySelector('#score');
    if (isTouching(avatar, coin)) {
        scoreCount++;
    };
    scoreLabel.textContent = scoreCount;

    if(isTouching(avatar, coin)) moveCoin();
    });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



const extractPos = (position) => {
    if (!position) return 50;
    return parseInt(position.slice(0,-2))
};



const moveCoin = () => {
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerWidth)
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerHeight)
    coin.style.top = `${y}px`;
    coin.style.left = `${x}px`;
};
moveCoin();
```

```css
#player {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

#coin {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
}

#scoreBoard {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    border: 8px solid #FFD700;
}

label {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Coin Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="player" src="https://media.tenor.com/images/0791eb3858075aca85eed5ecfe08c778/tenor.gif" alt="">
  <img id="coin" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/coin-gif-png-7.gif" alt="">

<div id="scoreBoard">
  <label id="score">0</label>
</div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Andan, thank you so much. This gave me something to think about. I have a better perspective now. Amazingly simple but incredibly valuable to me.